# List view Context Menu not displayed when clicked continuously

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, contextmenu

I am developing a chat application using WPF (in which I am a noobie), I have created a list view in order to show contacts of recent chats as displayed in the image below. now I am displaying a context menu so that the user should able lo leave/mute/star a contact. what is happening here is that while continuously removing contacts in this list using this context menu after some operations it is not working. please find code regarding code behind and view below

This is my scenario:

[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="StarredContactsList" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StarredContacts}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Cursor="Hand"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myLBStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,-5,0,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="OnSelect_StarredContact">
    <ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="StarredListViewContextMenu" Background="White" StaysOpen="False" Margin="0,-15">
     <MenuItem Header="Close Conversation"  FontSize="12" Height="25" Visibility="{Binding IsPersonal,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Click="LeaveMenuItem_Click"/>
     <MenuItem Header="{Binding FullName}" HeaderStringFormat="Leave #{0}" Height="25" FontSize="12" Visibility="{Binding IsChannel, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Click="LeaveMenuItem_Click"/>
     <MenuItem FontSize="12" Header="{Binding MuteHeader}" Height="25" Click="MuteMenuItemClicked"/>
     <MenuItem FontSize="12" Header="Unstar Conversation" Height="25" Click="StarMenuItemClicked" Foreground="Black"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.Resources>
```

there is no behind for displaying context menu

i have linked this above context menu as follows[image]

Comment: if there is any other code or file needed to be checked just mention I'll be editing my question by uploading required files

Comment: This context menu befalls on the entire `ListView`. What you need is a context menu for each item in the list, is my first guess. Note that the focus doesn't change to the selected item when right clicking, but it always goes back to the first item. This can be causing the action to be applied on the first item each time.

Comment: yep it is taken care off!! altough focus goes to previous item/listview(say) there is no change

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, try something like this out:

```
<ListView >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu >
                        <MenuItem />
                        <MenuItem />
                         ...
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListViewItem.ContextMenu>
            </ListViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I don't know if this will fix it, so take this a suggestion :)

Comment: i get it i just have updated my question with linking context menu with respective item